# Where do I use the invisibility potion?

Tags: the-gold-factory

It says on the description for the invisibility potion:

> Effect: Makes you invisible, and allows you to see invisible objects

Where are there invisible objects to see? I'ver tried in all the quests I have at the moment and found nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are in the castle in the sky, you will need to fight someone who is invisible. As far as I can tell there are no other times to use this potion.

Comment: I found the castle, and he is telling me that he isn't ready to fight me yet.  I made an invisibility potion, but there is no option to drink it while in the castle. How do I advance?